# TypeScript - Error when using conditional types with enum in generic function

Tags: typescript, type-inference

I'm encountering an error while using a conditional type in a TypeScript function that has a condition based on an enum.

The enum:

```
export enum FactoryResult {
  INTERNAL_FORMALITY_CREATED_WITH_DOCS,
  INTERNAL_FORMALITY_INVALID_DOCS,
  INTERNAL_FORMALITY_MISSING_DOCS,
}
```

Here is the beginning of the function:

```
public fromData<T extends FactoryResult>(
  data: FormalityCreationDTO,
  filesAttachments: FileAttachment[],
): {
  factoryResult: T;
  formality: T extends FactoryResult.INTERNAL_FORMALITY_MISSING_DOCS ? never : formality;
  invalidDocuments: T extends FactoryResult.INTERNAL_FORMALITY_MISSING_DOCS ? never : FileAttachment[];
} {
   if (filesAttachments.length < NumberOfFilesRequiredForCreation.TEST) {
  return {
    factoryResult: FactoryResult.INTERNAL_FORMALITY_MISSING_DOCS, // <= error
  };
...
}}
```

In this function, I'm using a condition with conditional types to determine the types of `inpiFormality` and `invalidDocuments` based on the value of `T`. If `T` is a specific key of the `FactoryResult` enum, then both properties should be of type never, indicating that they may not be returned.

The error in the first condition of the function:

```
TS2322: Type 'FactoryResult.INTERNAL_FORMALITY_MISSING_DOCS' is not assignable to type 'T'.   'FactoryResult.INTERNAL_FORMALITY_MISSING_DOCS' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'FactoryResult'.
```

I'm trying to understand why this error is occurring.
Thank you for any help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assigning to a conditional type (returning a value of a certain type is an assignment), it really hard for TypeScript to allow. It has a very hard time trying to figure out which side of the condition is the right one to use.

But in the vast majority of cases, you don't need to.

---

Here `T` is only referenced in your return type, so it *cannot* be inferred from the input.

You are returning one of two values shapes, depending on a runtime value (the number of items in the `filesAttachments` array). So you *cannot* know at compile what will be returned. And that means that a generic type parameter is of no help to you.

So it turns out, this is not generic at all. It's just a function that returns a discriminated union of possibilities.

Create the type types that could be returned by your function:

```
type MissingDocsResult = {
  factoryResult: FactoryResult.INTERNAL_FORMALITY_MISSING_DOCS
}

type OtherResult = {
  factoryResult: FactoryResult.INTERNAL_FORMALITY_CREATED_WITH_DOCS | FactoryResult.INTERNAL_FORMALITY_INVALID_DOCS
  formality: string // use a type for whatever this is
  invalidDocuments: FileAttachment[]
}
```

And then make your function return those:

```
class A {
  public fromData<T extends FactoryResult>(
    data: FormalityCreationDTO,
    filesAttachments: FileAttachment[],
  ): MissingDocsResult | OtherResult { // function returns either shape
    if (filesAttachments.length < NumberOfFilesRequiredForCreation.TEST) {
      return { // works fine
        factoryResult: FactoryResult.INTERNAL_FORMALITY_MISSING_DOCS,
      }
    }

    return { // works fine
      factoryResult: FactoryResult.INTERNAL_FORMALITY_INVALID_DOCS,
      formality: 'a formality here',
      invalidDocuments: filesAttachments,
    }
  }
}
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9gJwLYEMA2BLUBhBEXAZwB2AIgCoDyUAvFAN6yKqY54FFlUBcUwCAV2gBfAFChIsDGggBBYMBQBjABZIIxYLQZSZ8xavWbe-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-lAeDAAICDEARhHCsSRr4oS1ESqa1JKpa9KMksoSrIMGyUWIv4WL+xGkeRQq-iKhoSnR0riq+jGKhadLWqEfQzAM6w7qJK5OrwADkganJpoBQJ+EDaepu6pummbZmBvBATIB7nkeYFmbx5hskAA)